# max_heapify procedure on heap

Tags: c++, heap

i have  these procedure

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int parent(int i ){
    return  i/2;
}

int left(int i ){
    return  2*i;
}

int right(int i){
    return 2*i+1;    
}

int a[]={ 27,17,3,16,10,1,5,7,12,4,8,9,10};
int n=sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

void max_Heapify(int i){
    int largest=0;
    int l=left(i);
    int r=right(i);
    if(l<=n && a[l]>a[i]){
        largest=l;
    }
    else{
        largest=i;
    }
    if(r< n && a[r]>a[largest]){
        largest=r;
    }
    if (largest!=i){
        int t=a[i];
        a[i]=a[largest];
        a[largest]=t;
    }
    max_Heapify(largest);
}

int main(){
     max_Heapify(2);
     for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
         cout<<a[i]<<"  ";
     }    
return 0;
}
```

when i run it compiles fine but after run  stops  ubnormaly  it's running why? please help
look at this code

```
Max-Heapify[2](A, i):
 left ← 2i
 right ← 2i + 1
 largest ← i
 if left ≤ heap-length[A] and A[left] > A[i] then:
 largest ← left
 if right ≤ heap-length[A] and A[right] > A[largest] then:
 largest ← right
 if largest ≠ i then:
 swap A[i] ↔ A[largest]
 Max-Heapify(A, largest)
```

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap).

Comment: What is it supposed to do? What exactly goes wrong? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: I don't see anything that terminates the recursion here.

Comment: here is  violating max-heap property on node 2 so i want correct it

Comment: so what will be correct form?

Comment: note that this code uses 1-based heap addressing, so the element at a[0] (27 in the example), will never be correctly placed in the heap, and max_Heapify(0) will fail miserably.

Answer (score 3):

You translated the pseudo-code from the Wikipedia article into C++ code, but you accidentally altered the logic.  In the Wikipedia article, you'll notice that the recursion only happens *conditionally*: that is, `if largest ≠ i`

```
if largest ≠ i then:
    swap A[i] ↔ A[largest]
    Max-Heapify(A, largest)
```

Translated into C++, this should read something like:

```
if (largest != i) {
  swap(a[i], a[largest]);
  Max_Heapify(largest);
}
```

Again, notice that the recursive call to `Max_Heapify` only happens *conditionally*, when `largest != i`.  In your code, you recursively call `Max_Heapify` *unconditionally*, meaning that you keep recursing no matter what.  So obviously your program is going to crash with a stack overflow.  Unlike iteration, you can't recurse infinitely because you quickly run out of stack space.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a base case to terminate the recursion, so I imagine you're eventually getting a stack overflow.  Think about when you can tell that you're done so you can gracefully fall out of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you shouldn't **always** call `max_Heapify` tail-recursively, but instead return when you've hit the bottom size of the sorting heap... What happens is that your program runs out of stack.

Also, check out `std::swap`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `max_Heapify` always recurses infinitely.  You are seeing a stack overflow (small s, small o).

If you step through your code in the debugger, this sort of thing will quickly be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version I wrote, you can take a look.

http://code.google.com/p/clibutils/source/browse/src/c_heap.c